# moving columns across rows

Tags: awk, columns

I am dealing with a txt file and trying to keep the first column/field in place, but shift the 2nd column down by 1 row. I tried this, but it gave the error unmatched .'s.

```
awk  '{for(i=1; i<NR; i++) FNR==i {print i, $(i+1)}}’ filename
```

Comment: Could you please provide input and output example?

Comment: What about the first line? Can you give the first three lines as they are and as they should be?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want

```
awk '{tmp = $2; $2 = prev; prev = tmp; print}' filename
```

Any whitespace between the columns will be collapsed to a single space.

example

```
$ seq 12 | paste - - -
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
10      11      12

$ seq 12 | paste - - - | awk '{tmp = $2; $2 = prev; prev = tmp; print}' 
1  3
4 2 6
7 5 9
10 8 12
```